# How to find elements from a Unity based (Android) app?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, appium, robotframework, inspector

I was study of applying automation tests on a Unity based (Android) app/game. The thing is, through Appium and Appium Inspector We cannot see any elements on my device screen, so I don’t know how to get the id’s correctly. Can someone provide any software tools list? Or have any idea for this?

Appium and Appium Inspector. Cannot see any elements on device screen.